# Best options for translating a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Since there are so many options there available for internationalization of a rails app, which gems or plugins are the best (today) for adding i18n support to a rails app.

Im using I18n bundled with rails for the application messages, button labels, and model attribue names.

But I also need to let the users to input content and the translated version of the content, but there are so many options for this right now that I don't really know which one to use.

Answer (score 2):

I like this one:
https://www.github.com/mynewsdesk/translate

because it has a nice webGUI for translating new/changed strings

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good way for handling the locales of the application. What do you think of globalize2 for model translation? is there any other better?

Comment: Well I tested it, and works fine for files directly inside the config/locales directory. But if you have a directory with yml files inside the config/locales like config/locales/views/es.yml, those files wont be loaded :(

Comment: I think I will go with Globalize2. It seems to do something like what I want.

Answer (score 2):

We at Mynewsdesk (the guys behind the translate plugin) has moved on, now we're using [Web Translate It](https://webtranslateit.com/) to manage our locales. We've bloged about our [translation workflow](http://devcorner.mynewsdesk.com/2011/04/14/translation-workflow/).